# foreignObject bug with Chrome with d3?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, d3.js

I've spent all day trying to work out what is going on with my code, and getting not very far.

If you check the following link in Firefox, everything is as expected;

http://jsfiddle.net/ZnkN6/50/

The behavior in Firefox is that hovering over the yellow dots highlights the time in the list of times below the date header.

However, in Chrome, something seems very broken. I can never get the last reading to highlight, and the highlighting of the other times doesn't feel right - sometimes artifacts are left over, sometimes two times are highlighted.

Am I asking for trouble by using `foreignObject`? Should I be somehow drawing the times to the screen using svg instead?

The mouseOver part of the code is as follows, but looking at the jsfiddle is the only real way to get a feel for what is going on.

```
      .on("mouseover", function(d){
                    d3.select(this).style('fill', 'black');
                    $('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');
                    var id = 'readinglog' + new Date(d).getTime();
                    $(document.getElementById(id)).addClass('highlighted');
                })
                .on("mouseout", function(d){
                    d3.select(this).style('fill', 'orange');
                    var id = 'readinglog' + new Date(d).getTime();
                    $(document.getElementById(id)).removeClass('highlighted');
                })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that Chrome doesn't redraw the element after its style has changed. So the class is assigned correctly, the display is just not updated. You can read more about this issue [here](http://www.eccesignum.org/blog/solving-display-refreshredrawrepaint-issues-in-webkit-browsers). I've implemented a solution along the lines of what's outlined there, hiding and showing the `foreignObject` element:

```
$('.readinglogpreviewvalues').hide();
$('.readinglogpreviewvalues').get(0).offsetHeight;
$('.readinglogpreviewvalues').show();
```

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZnkN6/51/). Works fine for me in Chrome.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was close to breaking point with this one.

Comment: I actually discovered this only by accident -- assigned the highlighting to the element manually (which didn't work), switched to another tab to google something and switched back. And there was the highlighting all of a sudden.